# Why adding two large integers whose result greater than int.MaxValue doesn't throw overflow exception?

Tags: c#, overflowexception

If we are using the following loop in a program, the loop never ends in C# 4.0

```
for (int i = 1; i <= int.MaxValue; i++)
{
}
```

This is because adding 1 to int.MaxValue (2147483647) will not result in an overflow exception, but results in -2147483648 (taking into consideration 32bit int and 2's compliment).

```
int i = int.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
```

It seems the behavior changed recently. [See the question Arithmetic operation caused OverflowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756542/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-adding-integers) .What could be the reason behind this change?

Comment: This loop should end when `i == int.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overflow exceptions for integer (and other integral types) are only done in [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) contexts.

So, this will cause an exception:

```
checked
{
 int i = int.MaxValue;
  Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
}
```

They are not set to do this by default as they are more expensive than simply overflowing.

From MSDN:

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

And:

> Overflow checking can be enabled by compiler options, environment configuration, or use of the checked keyword.

---

This is not a recent change - C# has been like this from  day one. What you see in the question is VB.NET code, which is by default in a checked context.

So, keeping to defaults, overflowing code in VB.NET will throw an exception, but identical code in C# will not.

Comment: That's interesting.  I didn't realize that the differences between VB.Net and C# were more than skin-deep.