# Solving ArithmeticOverflow calling AddrOfPinnedObject

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a lib to preview and capture snapshots from capture cards.

The lib: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr

It was built for .net 2.0 and everything works perfectly when those classes and controls are called from .net 2.0 or 3.5 projects.

When I add the reference to it from a .net 4.0 project, I am getting a fantastic exception.

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

when trying to:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(this.savedArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
int scan0 = (int)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

I would happily change my app to .net 2.0 but I need it to be in .net 4.0 to reference some other libs.

I have no idea how to solve this. I have tried to compile those libs in .net 4.0 and succeeded, but when executing that piece of code, same problem. Could it be a problem in .net 4.0?

I am lost. It would be perfect if you could provide some guidance in this matter.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756542/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-adding-integers

Comment: What does the Stack Trace show? Does it have any Inner Exception?

Comment: @Pavenhimself: Nice post, but not entirely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `int` is a 32-bit integer. If you are on a 64 bit machine, addresses aren't 32 bit, but 64 bits.

Use `Int64` (`long`) instead to match the processor's address length:

```
long scan0 = (long)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Or, even better, call [`ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint64(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
long scan0 = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to use IntPtr? Then it should work for either architecture.

Comment: @RenniePet: `handle` *is* an `IntPtr`.

Comment: Setting the build 'Platform target' to 'x86' solved to problem as well.
But it seems more correct to update the variable to long.
Thanks.

Comment: @user3149304: That is true because it runs as like it does on a 32 bit platform.