# What does -1.#IND00 mean?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-does-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-means)

I perform a subtract operation and  -1.#IND00 is what I get I am having trouble understanding what does it mean.Could someone help?

Comment: Duplicate of [What does 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-does-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-means)

Comment: Could there be a division by zero somewhere? Put some code maybe...

Comment: Yeah I guess i was dividing  by 0.Thanks @James and @littleadv.