# How to generate NaN, -Infinity and +Infinity in ANSI C?

Tags: c, nan, c89, infinity

I use ANSI C89 (not C++), and I want to generate `NaN`, `-Infinity` and `+Infinity`.

Is there any standard way (eg. standard macro)?
Or is there any platform and compiler independent way to generate these numbers?

```
float f = 0.0 / 0.0; // Is f ALWAYS in any platform is NaN?
```

Comment: Arbitrary platforms are not even required by the standard to support NaNs and infinities. I believe an IEEE 754 conformant implementation is required to support obtaining them by division, as in your example, though.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is in C99, but not in previous standards AFAIK.

In C99, you'll have `NAN` and `INFINITY` macros.

From **"Mathematics `<math.h>`"** (§7.12) section

> The macro **INFINITY** expands to a constant expression of type float representing positive or unsigned inﬁnity, if available; ...

If you're stuck with ANSI C89, you're out of luck. See [C-FAQ 14.9](http://c-faq.com/fp/nan.html).

Comment: You should say "ANSI C89". The current "ANSI C" is C99.

Comment: In C89, the macro `HUGE_VAL` is available to define infinity values.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE ANSI adopted ISO C99 in 2000. And current C is ISO C18 (or sometimes C17) and ANSI C18, though.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is standard or portable, but here's a start:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.c; make test; ./test
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 printf("%f\n", 1.0 / 0);
 printf("%f\n", -1.0 / 0);
 printf("%f\n", 0.0 / 0);
 return 0;
}
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3: warning: division by zero
test.c:4: warning: division by zero
test.c:5: warning: division by zero
inf
-inf
-nan
```

Strangely enough, I can't get positive NaN using this naive approach.

---

Also see this: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Comment: funny, that produces `inf -inf nan` (not `-nan`) with clang. not really sure what `-nan` is supposed to mean, actually :-)

Comment: Result of VS2010:
1.#INF00
-1.#INF00
-1.#IND00

Comment: [What do 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean)

Comment: @Mat Every float has a sign bit, always. You can get positive NaN (or any other number) for float `f` with `f | (1 << 31)`.

Comment: To get `-NaN`, use `-(0.f/0.f)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an old compiler where `INFINITY` does not exists you can also use the macro `HUGE_VAL` instead, also defined in the `<math.h>` library.

`HUGE_VAL` should be available in C89/C90 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1990).

References: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL

Answer (score 2):

There is an actual way to create infinity and negative infinity.  Based on the IEEE 754 standard, which C89 follows, infinity is defined as a floating point number containing all zeroes in the mantissa (first twenty-three bits), and all ones in the exponent (next eight bits).  `nan` is defined as any number with all ones in the exponent, and anything but all zeroes in the mantissa (because that's infinity).  The difficult part is generating this number, but this can be accomplished with the following code:

```
unsigned int p = 0x7F800000; // 0xFF << 23
unsigned int n = 0xFF800000; // 0xFF8 << 20
unsigned int pnan = 0x7F800001; // or anything above this up to 0x7FFFFFFF
unsigned int nnan = 0xFF800001; // or anything above this up to 0xFFFFFFFF

float positiveInfinity = *(float *)&p;
float negativeInfinity = *(float *)&n;
float positiveNaN = *(float *)&pnan;
float negativeNaN = *(float *)&nnan;
```

However, simply casting an `unsigned` to a `float` would result in the compiler creating a `float` of the same value.  So, what we have to do is force the compiler to read the memory as a float, which gives us the desired result.

Comment: This breaks strict aliasing. If possible, use `memcpy` or the traditional divide by zero method instead.