# How to express Infinity in C in a ruby extension

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-1.8, infinity

I want to do the equivalent of

```
::Infinity= 1.0/0
```

in a ruby extension which is written in C.

So far I have come up with

```
rb_const_set(rb_mKernel, rb_intern("Infinity"), rb_float_new(1.0/0));
```

which gives me a compiler warning due to division by zero. And

```
rb_const_set(rb_mKernel, rb_intern("Infinity"), rb_eval_string("1.0/0"));
```

which is ugly due to the usage of `eval`.

What is a clean proper solution to this?

Comment: Is there something you need that [`Float::INFINITY`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Float) doesn't provide?

Comment: hm, `Float::INFINITY` seems to work only in ruby1.9

Comment: `Float::INFINITY` was added in Ruby 1.9.2, which has been out for over 14 months now.

Comment: 1.8 is still wide spread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235847/how-to-generate-nan-infinity-and-infinity-in-ansi-c).

```
rb_const_set(rb_mKernel, rb_intern("Infinity"), rb_float_new(INFINITY));
```

There are no compiler warnings for this.