# Need to write the contents of the function

Tags: c

Have the source code. Content of the function func is unknown:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float func (void)
{
  // Black box
}

int main (void)
{
  float f1, f2;
  int r1, r2;

  f1 = 5.0f;
  f2 = func();

  r1 = (f1 > f2);
  r2 = (f1 <= f2);

  printf ("r1=%d r2=%d\n", r1, r2); 
  return 0;
}
```

Need to write the contents of the function func, to print out the message:

```
r1=0 r2=0
```

**Answer:**

> return pow(-5.0, 0.5);

or

> return 0.0/0.0;

Can't understand, why so?

Comment: Is this some sort of brain teaser?

Comment: Do you know what does it mean by `0.0/0.0` in C?

Comment: @haccks No, what is it?

Comment: That should be `math.h` not `cmath`. It's `C`.

Comment: Any NaN will do; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235847/how-to-generate-nan-infinity-and-infinity-in-ansi-c

Comment: @dima; Dividing a `0` by `0` produces `NaN`.

Comment: @haccks So what is the correct answer?

Comment: @haccks dividing any number by `0` produces `Floating point exception`, not `NaN`.

Comment: If `f1 > f2` is false(0) then `f1 <= f2` will be true(1) ... both of them will not be true(1) at the same time ...

Comment: No correct answer? Only unuseful comments..

Comment: @dima: Most comments are very useful, and there is not *one* correct answer. As stated by ecatmur, any comparison with `NaN` yield false, therefore any function that return `NaN` solves that "puzzle".

Comment: @ajay: Any undefined value is NaN. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw: *Both* `f1 > f2` and `f1 <= f2` can be false if `f2` is `NaN`.

Comment: @ajay I can not express the full extent of my gratitude =)

Comment: Actually the quiestion is what should i change in function func

Comment: just put `return NAN;`. `NAN` is a macro defined in `math.h` header.

Comment: @dima: I do not understand your question. First you said that *"Content of the function func is unknown"* and now *"what should i change in function func"* - So what do you really want?

Comment: @Martin R I mean what should I write, not change. The function funk is empty

Comment: @dima read this - http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the answer

```
return 0.0/0.0;
```

it will return [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Now in this case both `r1` and `r2` become `0`.

If you return

```
return pow(-5.0, 0.5);
```

the square root of a negative number is imaginary, and thus not representable as a real floating-point number, and so is represented by NaN. In this case both of `r1` and `r2` is `0`.
You function would look like:

```
float func (void)
{
     return 0.0/0.0 // return pow(-5.0, 0.5);
}
```

Another option is that, just return NaN. (include `<math.h>`).

```
float func (void)
{
    return NAN;
}
```

Comment: `pow(-5.0, 0.5)` returns `NaN`. `double pow(double, double)` does not return complex numbers.

Comment: @MartinR; I just read this on the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN :)

Comment: From "man pow": pow(x, y) returns a NaN and raises the "invalid" floating-point exception for finite x < 0 and finite non-integer y.

Comment: The macro is `NAN`, not `NaN`.