# How to pass infinity values to a function and test the result

Tags: c, c99, complex-numbers

I have this function:

```
#include <complex.h>
complex double f(complex double x, complex double y) {
  return x*y;
}
```

I would like to call it with `x = inf + i inf`  and `y = i inf` and see what the result is. In particular I want to test if the result is an infinity value (as it should be) or if it is `NaN + iNaN`. The reason for this is to test different C compilers.

> How do you do this in C?

Comment: See also [How to generate NaN, -Infinity and +Infinity in ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235847/how-to-generate-nan-infinity-and-infinity-in-ansi-c)

Comment: @chrisaycock Thank you that partly addresses it. However I need to create x = inf + i inf and also test if the result is NaN + iNaN or not.

Comment: I though that setting `0x7FFFFFFF` in a float created a `NaN`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you. I don't want to create a NaN.  I want to create x = inf + i inf and y = i inf and test if the result of the function is NaN + iNaN or not.

Comment: @eleanora Got it. I've retracted.

Comment: To create inf + inf i, use the CMPLX macro, that's what it's for.

Comment: @Cubbi Could you maybe add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an intermediate check, too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

complex double f(complex double x, complex double y) {
  return x*y;
}

int main(void){
  complex double x = INFINITY + INFINITY * I;
  complex double y = 0.0 + INFINITY * I;
  complex double ret;

  printf("x = %g + %g*I\n", creal(x), cimag(x));
  printf("y = %g + %g*I\n", creal(y), cimag(y));

  ret = f(x,y);

  printf("f = %g + %g*I\n", creal(ret), cimag(ret));

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Why?

Result with gcc-4.9.real (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4

```
x = nan + inf*I
y = nan + inf*I
f = -inf + -nan*I
```

Result with Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)

```
x = nan + inf*I
y = nan + inf*I
f = nan + nan*I
```

A complete and utter failure from the get go.

Comment: That's very confusing. Why do you get x = nan + inf*I ?

Comment: @eleanora I do not have the faintest idea (without looking into the compiler sources), you need to ask the authors of the respective compilers.

Comment: FWIW: `complex double x = CMPLX(DBL_MAX,DBL_MAX)*2;` generated "`x = inf + inf*I;`" on my platform that had the same "x = nan + inf*I" result for `complex double x = INFINITY + INFINITY * I;`

Comment: @chux and what platform exactly?

Comment: "i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0" "Intel Xeon" -std=c11

Comment: A clang dev has said that ""inf * I" == "(inf * 0 - 0*1) + (something)*I"" and it's probably a bug.

Comment: Keep in mind inf is viral in C99 complex math: a number is a complex infinity if either real or imaginary part is inf, even if the other part is nan.  That said, nan+nan i is a bug.

Comment: @Cubbi Yes that is what the Intel C compiler gives too.  I am waiting to see if they accept it's a bug.

Comment: clang 3.8 gives `x = nan + inf*I
y = nan + inf*I
f = -inf + -nan*I`  So it seems only the Intel Compiler is still broken.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure this is correct since I've never worked with complex numbers in C, but I've tried this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

double complex f(double complex x, double complex y) {
  return x*y;
}

int main(void)
{
    double complex z1 = INFINITY + INFINITY * I;
    double complex z2 = INFINITY + INFINITY * I;
    complex double result = f(z1, z2);
    printf("%f + i%f\n", creal(result), cimag(result));    
}
```

I used both clang 3.8 (C 11) and GCC 6.1 (C 11) and the result was:

> -inf + i-nan

Based on http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/INFINITY.

Apparently the macro  `INFINITY` is not always supported and thus defined. Check the link above for more info.

Comment: Infinity is fine, but gcc has no imaginary numbers, so those z1 and z2 are not what you think they are. They are inf+nan i, though that's still complex infinity and not NaN under C99 rules

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what is basically a complex literal using multiplication with the `I` macro (which also has a `_Complex_I` alias). A minor example creating such a value is seen below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main()
{
  complex c = INFINITY * I + INFINITY;
}
```

Comment: What this answer calls "complex literal", in C is a _constant_.  In C++  'The term “literal” generally designates, in this International Standard, those tokens that are called “constants” in ISO C.'  C++ footnote 21

Answer (score 1):

The function, as written, is fine, the problem is with the way the complex numbers with special values are created and interpreted.

If you just write

```
double complex z1 = I * INFINITY;
double complex z2 = INFINITY + I * INFINITY;
```

you may discover that most of the popular compilers today do not support C99's [imaginary numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Imaginary_floating_types), and this expression actually multiplies (0,1) by (inf,0) and then adds (inf,0) to the result.

With gcc, I get z1 = (nan, inf), z2 = (nan, inf), f(z1,z2) = (-inf, -nan)

with clang, I get z1 = (nan, inf), z2 = (nan, inf), f(z1,z2) = (-inf, -nan)

with icc, I get z1 = (-nan, inf), z2 = (-nan, inf), f(z1, z2) = (-nan, -nan)

The only compiler that defines I as a pure imaginary number that I have access to is the C compiler from Oracle Studio

with oracle studio, I get z1 = (0, inf), z2 = (inf, inf), f(z1,z2) = (-inf, inf)

Now this is not actually supposed to be a problem because in C, there is only one Complex Infinity, and every complex number whose one component is infinite is considered to be that infinity, even if the other component is NaN. All built-in arithmetic is [supposed to honor that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplication): so in my list above, only Intel appears to have a bug here where multiplication of two complex infinities gave a complex nan.

For the lazy compilers, C11 has a macro that saves the day: [CMPLX](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/CMPLX)

```
double complex z1 = CMPLX(0, INFINITY);
double complex z2 = CMPLX(INFINITY, INFINITY);
```

now,

with gcc, I get z1 = (0, inf), z2 = (inf, inf), f(z1,z2) = (-inf, inf)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a shame there is no obvious way to report an icc bug.

Comment: Do you recall which version of GCC you used to compile your last example (using `CMPLX`)? I'm getting an undefined symbol error at link time with my version(s) of GCC.