# Is it possible to parse "-1.#IND", etc using Double.Parse method

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to use `System.Double.Parse(string)` method for strings such as "-1.#IND" and "INF" representing special values results in a `FormatException`.

Is there any built-in .NET framework support to parse these?

Comment: What value you expect when you pass string -1.#IND to double.parse? I

Comment: @AshReva, I am quite sure [`double.NegativeInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity.aspx).

Comment: Actually `double.NaN`. "-1.#IND" seems to be standard representation created by some technologies.

Comment: *Some technologies* are not necessary standard and supported by .Net Framework.

Comment: For reference, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/347920/87399) talks about these string values. It looks like they're from the C/C++ standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the only non-numeric values `double.Parse` recognizes are the string values returned by `double.Nan.ToString()`, `double.PositiveInfinity.ToString()`, and `double.NegativeInfinity.ToString()` (dependent on Culture).

In your case I would just use a `switch`:

```
double dblValue;
switch strValue
{
   case "-1.#IND":
      dblValue = double.Nan;
      break;
   case "INF":
      dblValue = double.Infinity;
      break;
   //... other casess
   default:
      dblValue = double.Parse(strValue);
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` and other values are parsed in the specified culture (or neutral, if no culture is specified). You can play with those [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/U4K6Ea) if you want.

If you have to parse something more special, then just

```
public double MyParse(string text)
{
    if(text == "blablabla")
        return double.NaN;
    if(text.Contains("blablabla")) ...
    if(text.StartsWith(...
    return double.Parse(text);
}
```