# Solving equation for y

Tags: c++

When testing out the equation I get a `-1.#IND00` as an answer when it solves for `y`. I'm basically trying to create a program that solves for `y` give the equation below

> y=y/(3/17)-z+x/(a%2)+PI

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14

int main (void)
{
    int a=0;
    double z=0,x=0,y=0;

    printf("Values for x, z, and a:"); 
    scanf("%lf%lf%d", &x,&z,&a); 

    y = (((y/(double)(3/17)))-z + (x/(a%2))+PI); 
    printf("y = %lf\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The cast in `(double)(3/17)` is too late to change anything. You want to cast before the division - or just write `3.0`.

Comment: as @T.C. said the double cast is too late. also consider using `static_cast` over C-style casts. also check the return value of `scanf` to ensure you have read 3 valid values

Comment: That doesn't solve the equation for `y`, it just assigns a value to `y`. If you fix the division by zero, the value will be `-z + (x/(a%2))+PI`.  You're going to have to solve the equation yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no questionmarks, I assume the question is "How do you write a C++ program that solves this equation?"

C++ is a programming language and by itself is not able to solve your equation, i.e. C++ won't do any transformation to your equation to get it into a form where `y` occurs only on the lefthand side and all parameters on the righthand side. You have to transform it yourself, manually or by using a solver.

What happens in the posted code?

Lets start at the leftmost part of the equation `y/(double)(3/17)` from inside out according to the parentheses:

- `3/17` is interpreted as integer division, which results in `0`;
- `(double)(0)` casts the integer `0` into a double of `0.0`;
- `y/0.0` is a division by 0 as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean) which results in your error.

You could fix this as pointed out in the comments by either casting the first integer like `(double)3/17` or turning the integer `3` into a double `3.0` or using `static_cast`.

- However, `y` is still initialized to 0, so `y/(double)3/17` is `0` and the equation calculated is basically `-z + x/(a%2) + PI`.

So, unless you transform the equation and put the transformed equation into the code, you won't get the results you expect.