# Wierd output while using glutPassiveMotionFunc in openGl

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to make a circle drawn using glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,20); follow my cursor postion
I am developing this as a part of a small game
for that i am using the following functions

```
void main()
{   ...
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_co_ordinates);
    ...
}

void mouse_co_ordinates(int x,int y)
{
  printf("%d %d\n",x,y); //circle will be made to follow these co-ordinates
}
```

executing this and moving the mouse in the window gives the below out put

403 21
-1.#IND00 -1.#IND00
402 28
402 43
402 60
402 79

I dont understand what is "-1.#IND00 -1.#IND00"
Any help will be usefull

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean)

Comment: Thanx @JoshPetrie
But still confused, why did glutPassiveMotionFunc receive an invalid number as a parameter