# -1.#IND00 results from fourier series sum

Tags: c

I'm getting the "-1.#IND00" as a solution to this Fourier series.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n, x=50, L=100, q1=2;
    float pi = 3.141592;
    float flux1=0;
    double flux2=0;

        for(n=0;n<=50;n++)
        {
            flux1=q1*(2/(pi*n))*(cos(n*pi)-1)*(sin((n*pi*(x+L))/(2*L)));
            flux2+=flux1;
        }
        flux2+=q1;
        printf("%f\n", flux2);

    return 0;
}
```

flux2 is coming out as "-1.#IND00" I can't work out why, since each term in the sum, (flux1), comes out as a rational number and the sum seems to converge.

Can you guys help?

Comment: Why are you using `float` mixed with `double`? Unless you want to satisfy an interface, there is very little reason to use a `float` on a modern machine.

Comment: [This old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/347940/440558) maybe can provide some clues.

Comment: *"since each term in the sum, (flux1), comes out as a rational number"* simply isn't true. `flux1` goes bad on the very first iteration, even after replacing all `int` and `float` with `double` (except `n`), adding `.0` to all literal integer numbers, improving the value of `pi`, and swapping the sequence of `sin((n*pi*...` to `sin((pi*n*...`.

Answer (score 2):

This computation is in error on the first iteration when `n == 0`

```
2.0/(pi*n)
```

It's a "divide by zero" error.

On subsequent iterations, the computation is good, but the sum `flux2` has already been corrupted by the bad value of the first `flux1` and never recovers.