# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-1.#IND00000000000e+000"

Tags: for-loop, input, numberformatexception

I was trying my model in BCVTB (a simulation software which connects EnergyPlus with MATLAB) and I found this error many times:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-1.#IND00000000000e+000"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at lbnl.actor.lib.net.Server.read(Server.java:266)
at lbnl.actor.lib.Simulator._readFromServer(Simulator.java:384)
at lbnl.actor.lib.Simulator.fire(Simulator.java:243)
at ptolemy.actor.AtomicActor.iterate(AtomicActor.java:496)
at ptolemy.actor.sched.StaticSchedulingDirector.fire(StaticSchedulingDirector.java:216)
at ptolemy.domains.sdf.kernel.SDFDirector.fire(SDFDirector.java:496)
at ptolemy.actor.CompositeActor.fire(CompositeActor.java:454)
at ptolemy.actor.Manager.iterate(Manager.java:792)
at ptolemy.actor.Manager.execute(Manager.java:356)
at ptolemy.actor.Manager.run(Manager.java:1202)
at ptolemy.actor.Manager$PtolemyRunThread.run(Manager.java:1807)
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me to solve it!

Comment: Posible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean)

Comment: Who knows? There isn't any code here that shows what it is complaining about.

Comment: Could you please provide the minimal example of your code?

Comment: Actually it's not a code. It's a simulation software which uses Java, but when I tried to run it, I have been given this error. I don't know, maybe it happened because Java updated itself automatically and the new version is not compatible with our model. But I don't know how to solve this error.