# Why does this floating point error occur with the output -1.#IND00?

Tags: c

```
printf("The Angle A Is: %f", (acos((b*b + c*c - a*a)/2*b*c)*180/3.14159265359));
```

This is a simple program which returns the angle A if the sides a, b, c are entered.

I have checked whether the triangle is possible or not.

```
if((a+b) <= c || (b+c) <= a || (c+a) <= b)
    return 0;
```

I am getting correct output for some inputs. For `1 1 1` I get `60`.

But for the input `7 7 7` I am getting `-1.#IND00` instead of the `60` I should be getting.

Now I came to know by reading [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean) that it stands for indeterminate values (specifically a non-zero number divided by zero) but here that is not the case.

So why am I getting this error?

Here is the full program:

```
int main()
{
    float a, b, c;

    printf("Enter The Sides of The Triangle(a, b, c): ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    if((a+b) <= c || (b+c) <= a || (c+a) <= b)
    {
        printf("Triangle Not Possible.");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("The Angle A Is: %f", (acos((b*b + c*c - a*a)/2*b*c)*180/3.14159265359));
}
```

Comment: do not tag both C and C++. They're very different languages. Also learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/comment-page-1/)

Comment: @phuclv Sorry. I will remember that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses. Instead of writing `acos((b*b + c*c - a*a)/2*b*c)`,
 write `acos((b*b + c*c - a*a)/(2*b*c))`. Otherwise, `b*c` ends up in the numerator of your fraction, not the denominator, and you try to take the arccos of an impossible number.

Generally speaking, when you have a problem like this, it helps to simplify and break down the code. If `acos` returns an unexpected value, then it must have an incorrect argument. So calculate the argument to `acos`, put it in a variable, print *that*, make sure it's correct, and then move on.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the answer.