# Result is unrelated to expected when using pow in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PI 3.141592654
load();
main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int Reuse;
    int Opt;
    float Num1, Num2 ,ans;
    char oper;
    while (i < 20){
    load();
    i++;
}
    printf("Loading done!!");
    Sleep(2000);
    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to our calculator.\n");
    Reuse = 1;
    while (Reuse == 1){
        printf("\n\nWhich mode do you want to use?\n1.Normal maths operations\n2.Trigonometric functions\n3.Exit\nYour input: ");
        scanf("%d", &Opt);
        if (Opt == 1){
            printf("Your two numbers: ");
            scanf("%f%f", &Num1, &Num2);
            printf("Your operation symbol: ");
            scanf(" %c", &oper);
            if (oper == '+'){
                ans = (Num1 + Num2);
                printf("Here is your answer:\n%f  %c %f = %.5f (To 5 decimal places)\n\n", Num1, oper, Num2, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == '-'){
                ans = (Num1 - Num2);
                printf("Here is your answer:\n%f  %c %f = %.5f (to 5 decimal places)\n\n", Num1, oper, Num2, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == '/'){
                ans = (Num1 / Num2);
                printf("Here is your answer:\n%f  %c %f = %.5f (to 5 decimal places)\n\n", Num1, oper, Num2, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == '*'){
                ans = (Num1 * Num2);
                printf("Here is your answer:\n %f  %c %f = %.5f (to 5 decimal places)\n\n", Num1, oper, Num2, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == '^'){
                ans = (pow (Num1 , Num2));
                printf("Here is your answer:\n %f  %c %f = %.5f (to 5 decimal places)\n\n", Num1, oper, Num2, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else{
                    printf("\n\nYour input operator is incorrect; ERROR 1 Sintek");
                    Sleep(2450);
                    system("cls");
                }
        }
            if (Opt == 2){
                printf("Input your angle in degrees: ");
                scanf("%f", &Num1);
                printf("The trigo you are going to use\ns for sine\nc for cosine\nt for tangent\nYour input: ");
                scanf(" %c", &oper);
                if (oper == 's'){
                ans = (sin (Num1 * PI/180));
                printf("\nHere is your answer:\nAngle: %f\nSin%f = %f", Num1, Num1, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == 'c'){
                ans = (cos (Num1 * PI/180));
                printf("\nHere is your answer:\nAngle: %f\nCos%f = %f", Num1, Num1, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else if (oper == 't'){
                ans = (tan (Num1 * PI/180));
                printf("\nHere is your answer:\nAngle: %f\nTan%f = %f", Num1, Num1, ans);
                Sleep(2450);
                } else{
                    printf("\n\nWrong operator used for Trigo; ERROR 1 Sintek");
                }
            }
            if (Opt == 3){
                printf("Thank you for visiting my calculator, wish you come back soon!!");
                Sleep(3990);
                system("cls");
                exit(0);
            }

        }
}




load(){
    system("cls");
    printf("\\ LOADING /");
    Sleep(15);
    system("cls");
    printf("| LOADING -");
    Sleep(15);
    system("cls");
    printf("/ LOADING \\");
    Sleep(15);
    system("cls");
    printf("- LOADING |");
    Sleep(15);
    system("cls");
    printf("  LOADING  ");
    Sleep(3);
    system("cls");
}
```

the above is my code. when running the power function, the `pow()` in one of the if-else loop which is inside of the while loop, isnt outputing any numerical values, not even a incorrect number, but a phrase : `1.#Info`. other than that the code functions properly and smoothly. If you guys have any improvements to make my code outstanding, please state too.

```
Which mode do you want to use?
1.Normal maths operations
2.Trigonometric functions
3.Exit
Your input: 1
Your two numbers: 432 543
Your operation symbol: ^
Here is your answer:
 432.000000  ^ 543.000000 = 1.#INF0 (to 5 decimal places)
```

Comment: Hint: what is the result of 432^543, and what is the range of a `float`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean)

Comment: 432^543 --> about 1.168e+1431‬.  Likely need `long double`., but even that may not be enough.

Comment: Code uses `float` yet calls `double` functions like `sin(),tan(), pow()`  UnfreeHeX, What C compiler are you using?

Comment: Since code is doing double math, might as well use a more precise `PI` such as 3.1415926535897932384626433832795‬.  No harm to have an overly precise constant in code.

Comment: Printing FP numbers with `"%.5f"` takes the floating out of floating-point.  Suggest `"%g"`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The complier is from school. it looks like code blocks but its called allylocal.

Answer (score 1):

432.0^543.0 overflow. Make sure your result in range of float.
I suggest you use double rather float, double has a greater range.